# Run ManagedBean on startup

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I'm doing a project with JSF and I want to populate my database on startup (like a seed file in Rails), I've searched this forum but the answers didn't worked for me, here is the code:

DatabaseSeed.java:

```
package it.polimi.meteocal.business.control;

import it.polimi.meteocal.business.entity.User;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
public class DatabaseSeed {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    private User user;

    /**
     *  Initialize database values
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        user.setIdUser(1);
        user.setEmail("provaprova@gmail.com");
        user.setGroupname("USERS");
        user.setName("Provaseed");
        user.setSurname("Provaseed");
        user.setPassword("prova");
        user.setUsername("prova");

        em.persist(user);
    }

}
```

and in faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean> 
  <managed-bean-name>DatabaseSeed</managed-bean-name> 
  <managed-bean-class>it.polimi.meteocal.business.control</managed-bean-class> 
  <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

But when I run the application nothing is inserted into the db

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 mistakes:

- You declared the managed bean by both annotation and XML config. When a managed bean is declared both ways, the XML way takes precedence. You didn't set `eager=true` in XML, so it's not eagerly initialized anymore.

  Just get rid of `<managed-bean>` in `faces-config.xml`. That's the legacy JSF 1.x way which isn't necessary in JSF 2.x.
- You used a CDI managed bean scope `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` on a JSF managed bean `@ManagedBean`. This won't work. You need to declare a JSF managed bean scope, otherwise it will default to `@RequestScoped`.

  Replace

  ```
  import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
  ```

  by

  ```
  import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
  ```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if the bean is nowhere used in any JSF artifact, you'd better use `@Singleton @Startup` EJB instead. Moreover, having a `@PersistenceContext` in a JSF managed bean is a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` is deprecated and doesn't seem to work anymore. Instead, you can use an `@ApplicationScoped` bean that has a method with an `@Observes Startup` parameter. Then the method annotated with `@PostConstruct` gets called at startup.

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Startup;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SystemStartStop {
  
  /**
   * The parameter `@Observes Startup` makes sure that the dependency injection framework
   * calls this method on system startup. And to do that, it needs to
   * call `@PostConstruct start()` first.
   */
  private void forceEagerInitialization(@Observes Startup startup) {
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void start() {
    // This runs first.
  }
}
```